# Tomcat 8 (JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved...)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I'm using Tomcat 8 and trying to get some JSTL 1.2 functionality, but I keep on getting errors. I've looked at all the other SO posts regarding this JSTL issue, but none of them seem to solve the issue for me.

My `search.jsp` file starts with:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

My `web.xml` file has:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
```

And I have `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar` and `jstl-api-1.2.jar` ONLY in my `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder.

Are there any glaring errors in the snippets I've supplied? I'm not using Maven, just moving `.jar` s into the aforementioned `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder. Also, I don't know if this will help, but if I refresh the page for the `search.jsp` file, I sometimes get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

OR

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.search_jsp
```

Comment: You installed two different versions of the API and not a single impl. See duplicate for the link to the right JSTL link (it contains both API and impl in single JAR flavor)

Comment: @BalusC Ah, it works! Thanks so much for the pointer!